# Magento 2 error with the json file

Tags: magento, magento2

I'm installing magento2
when i running the command on macos "sudo composer install", it's showing the error, see the file i have attached
how to fix that problem, thanks
[image]

Comment: Please show the code and error messages in the body of the question, not as screenshots on external websites. See the discussion in http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON file at

```
/Users/james/.composer/auth.json
```

contains text that is not a valid JSON string.  Correct this, and you should be all set. (hint: post the contents of this (with credentials blanked out) in your question and someone can probably help you fix it.